# spacing on right of mobile site with no apparent cause Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a site for a client that was initally developed by another company. We were called in to fix their sites to be responsive.

I can't seem to locate the cause of the extra spacing.

It only shows up on devices and the responsive inspector: Resizing the window w/o inspector active does not create the issue.

http://www.criminalattorneylongislandny.com/

I've checked for the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` it is present.

Hovering over the html element and body elements, they are the proper "size" but they do not show any element bleed outside of the area, and yet the issue persists.

It displays correctly on an actual ipad, but the inspector is messed up.

The body has

```
body {
    min-width: -webkit-min-content;
    min-width: -moz-min-content;
    min-width: min-content;
}
```

wrapper

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've tried removing the body min-content, but it had no effect. I also tried to change the wrapper to have 100% max width, again, it was ineffective.

Landscape on phone is too wide,
Landscape on 320px portrait is the right width, but has the background image showing unnecessarily with a swipe to the left.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't see any apparent padding on the right of the screen when viewing with the responsive inspector on Chrome. Can you attach a screenshot, maybe?

Comment: yes its clear on responsive view

Comment: Added picture to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's that Mirsky logo in the footer that is sticking out. Remove the padding, display: block and perhaps add a max-width: 100% to it.

Comment: And Thank you :) I'm always surprised how easy it is to miss things like that. I reduced the padding to 25px. The max width wasn't having it with 64 px padding on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of `#click-menu` applies with inline style `top: 173px !important;`

Comment: Thats actually something of a quirk with all of their sites. The problem I was having was fixed. This is another one entirely. that inline important tag is being added by JS or php, havn't found the problem area yet. Viewed on an actual device, it displays properly. The previous developers only considered the devices, not desktop too.

I have discovered that setting the position to "initial" generally fixes this issue, and is being implemented across their sites.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.copyright li img.alignright 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```